# Google Pay Push Provisioning android demo app

Tags: android, android-pay

I am trying to develop a feature in my native android app where user can add/push his or her card to google wallet.

Unable to find tutorial to develop this feature.

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for Google Pay Push Provisioning: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android?authuser=1
You will need to submit a form to get access for the documentation.

Sample APP: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/android-sample-app?authuser=1